# How to prevent my swing components from scattering

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel, frame

I am using border layout in my frame and I have used different panels in various regions of the border layout. But when I maximize my frame the components scatter all over the place and the panels are ousted from the frame. Which property should I be manipulating to prevent this?

Comment: You need to provide code. It's _impossible_ to guess what's going on.

Comment: this is correct output from null layout or by using setSize

Comment: I have tried using null layout as well. However the components scatter when i try to maximise it

Comment: The code and a screenshot would be beautiful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Absolute Positioning by making `setLayout(null)`.
 Check [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html) for example.
If problem persists try using [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) or open-source MiG Layout.MiG Layout is helpful in designing complex UI.